# UIImage in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

This code should save am uiimage to core data. The image is stored in it's own entity and liked to another entity (relationship)

```
   NSEntityDescription *imageEntity = [ NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kImage inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [imageEntity setValue:self.image forKey:kPicture];

    [newPerson setValue:imageEntity forKey:kPicture];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save new associate: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Here I try to get it back , to put it in an uiimageview on a custom cell

```
  Person *crt = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.name.text = crt.name;
    Image *img = crt.picture;
    cell.image.image = img.picture;
```

This only works when the picture is first added ... after restarting the app the image does not show again.. Why is that? It's set as a transformable attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `UIImage` only as binary data. So what you need to do it set your entity's attribute type to `Binary Data`, and the use the `CoreGraphics'` method `UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image)`, which returns `NSData` and save it this way. And if you want to extract it from the database, you get the `NSData` and create an image with `[UIimage imageWithData:(NSData *data)]` method.
But I think the best implementation is to store only the local path to the image in your database, but the actual file is stored in a folder in your app's Documents folder... just a suggestion.

Comment: The wierd part is that I do this somewhere else also (save the image (a small png)) as Transformable ... and there it works ...